# Leverice commands list

Tags: message

I've been using Leverice and know /archive works in the message text box when using it as a command line (to archive the current active channel), but am looking for a digest of other commands I can use in the command line. Does anyone have a list handy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I have so far on Unix-like commands that can be entered into the message text box in Leverice (and these are case-sensitive):

**/archive** ----- archive current active channel

**/retrieveProject** ------ reload workspace and clear cache

**/unsubscribe** ----- unsubscribe from current active channel

**/mute** ----- mute current active channel and its child channels

**/unmute** ----- unmute current active channel and its child channels

**/renameUser -f FirstName -l LastName** ----- this will change the name on your user profile

**/cd /a/b/c** ----- go to specific channel in a branch

**/cd ..** ----- go to parent channel of current active channel

**/cd ../NameOfChannel** ----- go to specific channel by name of the channel